# Algorithm to add all lucky numbers under [N] to a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

A lucky number is defined as a positive integer whose decimal representation contains only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.

Now, suppose I want to add all Lucky Numbers under a given integer [N] to a vector, without using recursion. For the sake of simplicity, let N = 1000.

I came up with an approach to just check each digit of all the numbers under [N] by making seperate loops for 1 digit numbers, 2 digit numbers etc.

```
for(int number=0;number<10;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //1 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=10;number<100;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //2 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=100;number<1000;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //3 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=1000;number<10000;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))&&(((number/1000)%10==7)||((number/1000)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //4 Digit Lucky Numbers
```

I was thinking that this could roughly be converted to something along these lines but I am not quite able to come up with what exactly to do.

```
for(number;number<10*itr_counter;number++)
    {
    if(((number%10*itr_counter==4)||(number%10*itr_counter==7))) {lucky.push_back(number);}
    itr_counter*=10;
    }
```

I basically want to check each digit of all 1 digit numbers by taking modulo 10 and checking if the digits are 4 or 7. 
Similarly for a number consisting of X digits, I am taking modulo and dividing the number by 10, 100 and so on to check against 4 or 7.

Is this a good approach to the said problem? Also, can someone help me optimise the first block of code into something smaller and more efficient? Something along the lines of the second block of code would work.

Comment: What is your question?  If the implied question was "is this a good approach" I think not.  For a D digit number made of the digits `4` and `7` I would replace the bits 0 and 1 in a D bit number.  For a number of up to D digits, I would do that in a loop up to D.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but looks like you are looking for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I did not know about codereview. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianHackl, Whilst [CodeReview.SE] does handle reviews, and some optimisation of algorithm, the code needs to be in working conditions firstly! Please see [a Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @JSF I am sorry but I don't quite get your binary approach. Could you expand, please?

Comment: @holroy: I know. I did not mean that this question could be transferred to Code Review as it is, but clearly the author's intention is getting a review of the code.

Comment: @holroy The first block works correctly, I need to optimise it to make it somewhat look like the second block I posted. That does qualify, I guess.

Comment: I don't normally like to provide homework help by just doing it.  But I have no other useful reply to "expand" on the idea I gave above.  At that point C++ is a much clearer language than English for describing the idea.  I hope it helps you learn to think in the way illustrated for future problems, rather than just saving you from needing to figure it out this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Use a D bit number as a proxy for a D digit number
// Then use L=2^D as a proxy for D in a loop through required values of D
// Notice D is only implied, we don't need to actually store it.
for (unsigned L=2; ; L*=2)
{
   // Loop through all D bit numbers (which happen to be all numbers less than L
   for (unsigned N=0; N<L; ++N)
   {
      // Convert that D bit number into a D digit number
      unsigned long long X = 0;
      // Loop through the bits of N converting to digits
      for ( unsigned B=L; (B>>=1)>0; )
      {
         X = X * 10 + 4;
         if ( B & N ) X += 3;  // change the 4 to a 7.
      }
      if ( X > MAX_NUMBER )
         return;  // break out of two levels of loop
      lucky.push_back( X );
   }
}
```

That may look excessively tricky for such a simple task.  But if MAX_NUMBER were seriously large, this approach is far better than testing whether numbers are "lucky".

Also notice this methods finishes (detects completion) at an awkward point in the flow of the code (inside two levels of loop).  In serious programming that kind of thing is pretty common.  My overwhelming preference in that situation is to put the entire nested loop into a function so that I can use `return` from the function as an easy way to `break` two levels of loop.  Structured programming fanatics may be highly offended by that use of `return`.  You can accomplish the same flow control by mixing a `done` flag into the control of each loop.  That approach offends me as much as this `return` offends a structured programming fanatic.

A bit more detail on the two tricky loops:

Conceptually we have D and we want it to start at 1 and count up until we hit the return instruction and we want to compute `L=1<<D` meaning the number whose only set bit is in position D.  But instead we skip D entirely and compute L directly.

Then we want the inner-most loop to have a bit number E and conceptually count down the bit positions below D:

```
for (E=D-1; E>=0; --E)
```

And we want to similarly compute `B=1<<E` as the number whose only set bit is in position E.  But again we don't have D and we don't need E, we can compute B directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a scatterplot graphic and use `Gradient descendant` algorithm and a `machine learning` for estimate your values ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you aren't scanning a list to find lucky numbers in a set, instead you're generating a list of all the possible combinations of numbers between 0 and N that contain those digits; Wouldn't it be more efficient to simply generate all lucky numbers using a simple function?

Answer (score 0):

As you are not parsing a list verifying that the numbers are lucky numbers, you are much better off building the list/vector of lucky numbers using a function.

One way to approach this is to count in binary from 0 to the given digits you're aiming for. For `n=1000` that would be to `0b111 = 7`, and then replace each 0 with a 4, and each 1 with a 7. i.e. `0b101 = 747`. Then you can easily sum up the resulting vector.

Regarding your iterative approach of verifying it as a lucky number I would make a function something like the following in pseduocode:

```
while number > 0:
   lastDigit = number % 10
   if lastDigit != 4 and lastDigit != 7
       return false
   number = number / 10

return true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_lucky(int check_num)
{
while(check_num!=0)
    {
    if((check_num%10!=4)&&(check_num%10!=7))
        {
        return false;
        }
    check_num/=10;
    }
return true;
}

int main()
{
std::vector <long long> lucky;
for(int in_num=1;in_num<1000;in_num++)
    {
    if(is_lucky(in_num))
        {
        lucky.push_back(in_num);
        }
    }
}
```

I was finally able to make this `is_lucky` function which still isn't the most efficient way to do the task, but seems to be shortest way to do the task.

Comment: What were you supposed to learn in this assignment?  In real programming, sometimes short and obvious is better than efficient.  You just showed a pretty short and obvious approach to the problem.  Sometimes efficient is more important.  Since "lucky" numbers are useless and only given as a learning exercise, I don't know which your instructor hoped you would learn.  Certainly this answer is a big step forward from what you put in the original question.

Comment: I see you made the type inside your result vector `long long`.  But you didn't make any of the related values (such as the input to `is_lucky`) bigger than `int`.  Regardless of which type is better, consistency about that kind of thing is better than inconsistency.  If efficiency were what you were supposed to learn, then testing the behavior for very large numbers would be relevant and `int` might be too small.

Comment: I was supposed to learn bits and pieces of everything, really. But this was just more of a focus on how to approach problems for competitive programming. The original task only needs 'lucky' numbers under 1000, so the obvious thing to do is just to figure out all the numbers in your brain and put them in an array, but that doesn't really help to learn programming or exercise your brain, does it? Also, I did not realise the `long long` and `int` mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The solution similar to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) works, but it far from being smart.

Consider putting every value in a ordered vector: the n-th element is going to be composed of one of the previous elements plus a final '4' o '7'. Keeping this in mind you can generate the numbers and not check for them.

Here's the idea

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX_NUMBER 1000

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lucky_numbers(0);

    if (lucky_numbers.size () == 0)
    {
        if (4 < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (4);
        if (7 < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (7);
    }

    bool exit = false;

    while (!exit)
    {
        int size = lucky_numbers.size ();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            int new_lucky_number = lucky_numbers[i] * 10 + 4;
            if (new_lucky_number < MAX_NUMBER &&
                std::find(lucky_numbers.begin(), lucky_numbers.end(), new_lucky_number) == lucky_numbers.end() )
            {
                lucky_numbers.push_back (new_lucky_number);
            }
            else if (new_lucky_number >= MAX_NUMBER)
            {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }

            new_lucky_number = lucky_numbers[i] * 10 + 7;
            if (new_lucky_number < MAX_NUMBER &&
                std::find(lucky_numbers.begin(), lucky_numbers.end(), new_lucky_number) == lucky_numbers.end() )
            {
                lucky_numbers.push_back (new_lucky_number);
            }
            else if (new_lucky_number >= MAX_NUMBER)
            {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int size = lucky_numbers.size ();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        std::cout << lucky_numbers[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Depending on the conditions of your problem, you can optimize out the use of std::find and make it even faster.

**Update**

After discussing the solution, here's the enhanced version. The checks are stille inline, but avoids the find the restarts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX_NUMBER 1000

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lucky_numbers(0);
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;

    if (lucky_numbers.size () == 0)
    {
        if (4 < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (4);
        if (7 < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (7);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; ; i++)
    {
        int new_lucky_number = lucky_numbers[i] * 10 + 4;

        if (new_lucky_number < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (new_lucky_number);
        else
            break;

        new_lucky_number = lucky_numbers[i] * 10 + 7;

        if (new_lucky_number < MAX_NUMBER)
            lucky_numbers.push_back (new_lucky_number);
        else
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < lucky_numbers.size () ; i++)
        std::cout << lucky_numbers[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea!  But you made it way harder than it should have been.  The std::find looks completely pointless, and the uses of 4 and 7 all over the code are messy, and tests against MAX_NUMBER in too many places.  One of the most important things in learning software engineering is organizing a program such that each key aspect is implemented in as few places as possible (which almost always means in just one place).

Comment: If you remove std::find then you'll end up with duplicated values. If you have a lucky:mibers such as { 4, 7, 44, 47, 74, 77 } and restart the loop you would come out with 44, which is already present. Of couse you can avoid the use of find, but you need append 4 and 7 only to the numbers that were appended to the vector at the previous step. This is doable, moving the indexes depends on the cardinality of the set of lucky numbers. This makes the code harder to understand for our friend.

Comment: I personally don't see the number of tests against MAX_NUMBER an issue, in the while loop it can be reduced from 4 to 2, but at the price of splitting the if (new_lucky_number < MAX_NUMBER && std::find ...) into two nested if, which makes IMHO the code harder to understand. Maintenability of the code is also extremely important.

Comment: You are just making things harder by capturing `size()`, comparing against it, restarting, etc.  The vector is written faster than it is read, so you can just read it without limit in one loop as if it were an infinite size input.  You only stop when you have produced a max size result.  (And if you never waste all that effort on `size` you never need to waste any on `find`)

Comment: Now I get your point, that makes the initial idea even nicer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes the idea from the answer by Ottavio Campana but demonstrates a principle of good software engineering, which is keep each distinct element of the work and each element of the design decisions in a single place in the code (see my comments on that earlier answer):

```
// Anywhere a type is a design decision, rather than an obvious choice, use a typedef
typedef unsigned long long number;
typedef std::vector<number> container;

// A function is usually the best way to centralize work.
// If the parameter passing cost exceeds the work, use an inline function
// and rely on the optimizer to sort it out
inline bool push_number(container& c, number n, number m)
{
   if (n>m) return false;
   c.push_back(n);
   return true;
}
```

...

```
number n=0;
unsigned i=0;
container c;
while ( push_number(c,n+4,MAX_NUMBER) && push_number(c,n+7, MAX_NUMBER) )
{
   n = 10 * c[i++];
}
```

Notice that the `>` operation in comparing to max appears **ONCE** in the code.  The 4 and 7 each appear **ONCE** in the code.  The multiply by 10 appears **ONCE** in the code.

As you get into more complicated problems, the extra effort to organize so such things each appear once becomes the biggest difference between sloppy programming and real software engineering.

If MAX_NUMBER came from a `#define` or any global place, then passing it twice makes much less sense than just directly using it inside the function.  But I object to `#define` for such things and object to globals nearly as much.  So I didn't want to code in the assumption that the max number is globally visible.  Passing it isn't good, but it isn't really bad.  In a real project, when you find yourself excessively passing things like `c` and `MAX_NUMBER` that is a hint that the work should be done by member functions of a class that has those things as member variables.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in hiding the data type using typedefs. It just makes the code harder to maintain. Also the while loop takes more time to be understood by someone else. Taking the check for > in a dedicate function is good, but imho the biggest quality enhancement is generating the numbers instead checking them, the rest is cosmetics.